# Rails Namespaced Model Not Triggering Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

Basic Group Model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@ItemType = 'GroupItem' # Base ItemType
  after_initialize :default_item_type

  has_many :group_assignments
  has_many :items, through: :group_assignments, source: :groupable, source_type: @@ItemType, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true

  private
  def default_item_type
    self.item_type = @@ItemType if self.new_record?
  end
end
```

Namespaced Model:

```
class Gradation::Group < Group
  @@ItemType = 'Gradation' # Base ItemType
  after_initialize :default_item_type

  has_many :group_assignments
  has_many :items, through: :group_assignments, source: :groupable, source_type: @@ItemType, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true
  private
  def default_item_type
    self.item_type = @@ItemType if self.new_record?
  end
end
```

I am attempting to have a field *item_type* be set on the *after_initialize* callback, but not matter what I do, the callback is only triggered on the regular group model and not the namespaced one.

I am struggling to understand why this is the expected behavior, and also how to get callbacks to work for the namespaced *Group*.

Comment: It might be odd to try this, but can you change `private` to `protected`? If I remember well, private methods are only usable by the Model, and protected methods are usable by the Model AND its inherited classes. Also, the callback `after_initialize` will be called a lot of times! It will be called every time you will retrieve the record. If you want to set a default value on the creation step of the record, use `before_create` instead ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The overall solution to my problem looks like this...

Base Group Model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@ItemType = 'GroupItem' # Base ItemType
  after_initialize :default_item_type

  has_many :group_assignments
  has_many :items, through: :group_assignments, source: :groupable, source_type: @@ItemType, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true

  private
  def default_item_type
    self.item_type = @@ItemType if self.new_record?
  end
end
```

Subclassed Group model with ItemType set to another arbitrary model (in app/models/groups/gradation_group.rb):

```
class Groups::GradationGroup < Group
  @@ItemType = 'Gradation'
  has_many :items, through: :group_assignments, source: :groupable, source_type: @@ItemType, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My understanding is I had to change the namespace to something that is not a class name.  I also had to change the group name to something other than what the *items* association will be composed of (in this case *Gradation*).

Answer (score 0):

Using the class variable here `@@ItemType = 'Gradation'` is not likely to help you out. In an initial modeling of this problem, the @@ItemType were stepping on each other, always giving you 'Gradation'

The following will work. You'll notice the differences:

1. move to constant for the class instead of class variable
2. changed the namespacing around

app/models/group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  ITEM_TYPE = 'GroupItem' # Base ItemType
  after_initialize :default_item_type

  private
  def default_item_type
    self.item_type = ITEM_TYPE if self.new_record?
  end
end
```

app/models/group/gradation.rb

```
class Group::Gradation < Group
  ITEM_TYPE = 'Gradation' # Base ItemType

  private
  def default_item_type
    self.item_type = ITEM_TYPE if self.new_record?
  end
end
```

Notes:

1. You cannot use the SingleTableInheritance here -- Rails expects there to be a gradations table
2. you must define `default_item_type` on each subclass so that it can pull the correct ITEM_TYPE

To get rid of #2 above, you could do this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  ITEM_TYPE = 'GroupItem' # Base ItemType
  after_initialize :default_item_type

  private
  def default_item_type
    self.item_type = "#{self.class}::ITEM_TYPE".constantize if self.new_record?
  end
end
```

Then, each subclass could be:

```
class Group::Graduation < Group
  ITEM_TYPE = 'Graduation' # Base ItemType  
end
```